# Узнать содержмое

Tags: php, html

Я только начал изучать HTML и PHP
Хочу знать, как получить текст который введёт пользователь.

Вот кусок кода:

```
 <input name="login" type="text" value="login" size="150" />
    <input name="add" type="button" onClick="<?php
    $text= (login.value);
    echo("alert('$text');");
    ?>" value="Добавить" /><body>
```

Конкретней интересует `$text= (login.value);`
Чему должна равняться данная переменная, чтобы получить введённые данные?
Буду очень признателен.

Comment: А мне можете ещё подскзать?
Как просто узнать содержимое value
Не используя скрипты
Просто потом идёт выполнение других процедур и пост запросы мне не нужны


Answer (score 2):

Ну то что ты написал работать не будет никогда.

тебе тут в помощь не PHP нужно а JS. 
Посмотри JQuery, как с помощью него вытянуть значение.

```
<input id="login" name="login" type="text" value="login" size="150" />
<input name="add" type="button" id="add" value="Добавить" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#add").click(function() {
       alert($("#login").val());
)};
});
</script>
```

примерно так

Comment: Благодарю Вас

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="login" id="login" type="text" value="login" size="150" />
<input name="add" type="button" onClick="alert(document.getElementById('login').value);" value="Добавить" />
```

Это javascript. Если вы хотите как-то передать значение php, вам нужно отправить форму с текстовым полем внутри.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action='index.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='login'>
<input type='submit'>    
</form>
```

а в принимающем скрипте (index.php):

```
$text = @$_POST["login"];
```